# Catch ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I have a function that is run once every second by a timer. The purpose of the function is to request data through an API and then update a list and some textboxes with the results. For the most part it runs like clockwork, but every couple of hours I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

For whatever reason, either that one API request fails or the list doesn't update fast enough. Either way the function tries to update texboxes and variables using an empty list, hence the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Now this data is mostly not being stored for any length of time, and the function would just run again in another second anyway if not for the error popping up and stalling everything. I hadn't used C# before I made this program so I'm not sure how best to utilize the "catch" statement to just make the program ignore it and keep going. Actually it would be good if the number of failures was logged in an integer variable so that the program could determine if something was actually wrong instead of just a momentary glitch. How would you write the catch statement for this?

```
        try
        { 
            GetQuoteResponse resp = GetQuoteResponse.GetQuote(questradeToken, quotesSymbolIds);
            List<Level1DataItem> quotes = resp.Quotes;

            QuoteStream_Data.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < quotes.Count; ++i)
            {
                Level1DataItem quote = quotes[i];
                QuoteStream_Data.Add(new QuoteStream_Entry { lastTradePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(quote.m_lastTradePrice)});
            }

            XIVPriceBox.Invoke(new Action(() => XIVPriceBox.Text = QuoteStream_Data[0].lastTradePrice.ToString()));
            HVIPriceBox.Invoke(new Action(() => HVIPriceBox.Text = QuoteStream_Data[1].lastTradePrice.ToString()));
            TVIXPriceBox.Invoke(new Action(() => TVIXPriceBox.Text = QuoteStream_Data[2].lastTradePrice.ToString()));

            XIVCurrentPrice = QuoteStream_Data[0].lastTradePrice;
            TVIXCurrentPrice = QuoteStream_Data[2].lastTradePrice;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't.  `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is usually due to **programmer** error, not a failure on the program's part.  Part of your program may be falling victim to threading issues.  Where and how is `QuoteStream_Data` defined?  If it's static, that might be part of your problem.  Why are you clearing it?  You're only taking three entries, so why not just a regular limited queue?  Why can't you just re-use (leave alone) the old value if there isn't a new one?  Do you even need the stream afterwards, if there were more than three entries?

Comment: QuoteStream_Data is defined near the top of the form's public partial class: List<QuoteStream_Entry> QuoteStream_Data = new List<QuoteStream_Entry>(); I'm clearing it because I only need the list long enough to read the values into their proper places. Letting it accumulate values would make it more cumbersome for me to access.

Comment: Actually should have mentioned, each of the 3 entries in the list represents a different item. It's not a history of the same item.

Comment: Then yeah, your design is suspect.  If you're only reading it during this method (and clearing during run), then you essentially have a method-local variable.  Why not just use a regular method-local array?  If you get additional or fewer entries, how do you know which are the matching ones?  If you got two entries, which companies are they quotes for?  If you got an extra one, what do you do with the extra?  You can certainly catch your current exception, but you're starting from a false premise.

Comment: It wouldn't supply more or less entries than what it was set for. The "GetQuoteResponse" command comes from a dll file supplied with the API's sample app. And the sample app was designed to display these values in a grid format so I've stuck with that to some degree. Now that you mention it, I guess it would be possible to overwrite each value in sequence and not leave them blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
 try
 {
    // ...
 } 
 catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
 {
    LogException(ex);
 }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I create a method named LogException? What should it do?

Comment: That's just an example. If you want, you can instead just say `catch(ArgumentException) { exceptionCount++; }`.